# How to insert values in the beginning in the array using loop

Tags: php, loops

I want to display even and odd number both in the same array using loop. how can I do that in PHP ? I want to insert even number first and odd later.

I was trying to store even `$i` index of the array and odd in `$j` of the array but how can I now add first even then odd.

Output should be in single array

```
 2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9
```

Comment: `array_merge(range(2,8,2), range(1,9,2));`

Comment: @NigelRen $number=10;
for ($i=0; $i < $number; $i++) {
if ($i%2==0) {
  $even[$i]=$i;
 } 
 else{

  $odd[$i]=$i;
 }
}

Comment: @misorude  I don't want to merge .I wanted to know how it works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run loop for even number and store it in the array and in the same way run the loop for odd numbers

```
$array = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++)
{
 if($i%2 == 0)
 {
   $array[] = $i;
 }
}

for($i = 1; $i < 9; $i++)
{
 if($i%2 == 1)
 {
   $array[] = $i;
 }
}
print_r($array);
```

Here is the [demo](https://3v4l.org/PIh7X)

Comment: Wouldn't `for($i = 1; $i < 9; $i+=2)` make more sense and then you wouldn't have to test `if($i%2 == 0)`?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes.. but it would be for odd numbers. Then for even numbers we need to start the loop from `0`

Comment: Sorry - how about `for($i = 2; $i < 9; $i+=2)`

Comment: It will work though. But in the case if we have dynamic numbers then it would be more tricky to do in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Another algorithm looping 1 time depends also on the Modulo operator

```
<?php

$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

$odd = [];
$even = [];

foreach($array as $num){
    if ($num % 2){
        $odd[] = $num;
    } else {
        $even[] = $num;
    }
}
$finalArray = array_merge($even, $odd);

var_dump($finalArray);
```

This outputs

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(6)
  [3]=>
  int(8)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
  [5]=>
  int(3)
  [6]=>
  int(5)
  [7]=>
  int(7)
  [8]=>
  int(9)
}
```

Live demo https://3v4l.org/k7CmG